# Proving oblique asymptote of rational function for students using animation plot?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot this asymptotic $(\Delta ):y=x+1$ of this rational function $f(x) := (x^2+2x+2)/( x + 1)$  , using the below code But I didn't get it , and in the same time I want to show my students in plot that the distance between  two points $M\in (C_f) $ , $M' \in (\Delta )$ go to $0$ or vanish for $|x|$ large enough, And it is good to show the animation or the motion of points $M$ and $M'$ by increasing the values of $|x|$ to show them the behavior of that distance

```
 f[x_] := (x^2+2x+2)/( x + 1);
    Plot[{f[x], y==x+1}, {x, -11, 7}, Exclusions -> {y==x+1}, 
     ExclusionsStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, PlotRange -> 10, 
     AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
     Epilog -> {Text[y== x+1, {-5, -8}], Text[y ==x+1, {5, 2}]}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

A simple version on the subject. You can adopt this to your purposes.

```
f[x_]:=(x^2+2x+2)/(x+1);
a[x_]:=x+1;
Manipulate[
Plot[{f[x],a[x]},{x,-11,7},
Epilog->{Blue, Thick,Line[{{s,a[s]},{s,f[s]}}],
        PointSize[.015],Point[{{s,f[s]},{s,a[s]}}]},
Exclusions->{-1},
ExclusionsStyle->Directive[Purple,Thick,Dashed],
PlotStyle->{Black,Directive[Red,Thick,Dashed]},
PlotRange->{{-10,10},{-10,10}},
AspectRatio->Automatic,
PlotLegends->{(x^2+2x+2)/(x+1),x+1},
GridLines->Table[Range[-10,10],2],
PlotLabel->"DISTANCE to ASYMPTOTE = "<>ToString[Abs[f[s]-a[s]]],
ImageSize->Large],
{{s,0,"X-COORDINATE"},-10,10,N[Pi/10^5],Appearance->"Labeled"}]
```

Comment: I have copied that Code to wolfram cloud it doesn't work as yours i don't know why

Comment: @zeraouliarafik always good to include that you’re using wolfram cloud as opposed to a desktop version, can you clarify what problems it is having?

Comment: Can't speak on OP's behalf, but for me, in Wolfram Cloud, the blue point does not appear, and adjusting the slider makes it bug out; the slider itself vanishes, and the label displays some exposed variable (``FE`s$$776141109246748861804975270965864906424`` in my case)

Comment: What I can do to make it work  ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Read about functions and simplify code, start from bare-bone in Cloud. Cloud's frontend is a bit different from desktop. I used desktop to develop sophisticated interface -- you can play with it for free getting [TRIAL](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/trial). If you want this to work in cloud just strip down / simplify a bit the elements of interface and it will work. But for the sake of other community users I rather keep this full version.

Comment: I have tried animate instead of Manipualte seems works but not good

Comment: @zeraouliarafik there also could be some issue in the cloud, I will investigate. For the moment you can play with [desktop free version](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/trial)

Comment: @zeraouliarafik I fixed it -- see modified code -- it works now. Note `N[Pi/10^5]` and that functions `f` and `a` are now on separate lines. There is an issue in Cloud that is being fixed. But the updated version of the code works.

Comment: Thanks so much , pleas add the two points M and M' as given in the question , M in graph of f and M' for oblique asymptote